Как определить полноэкранный режим при F11
Описание
У браузеров есть собственный метод входа в полноэкранный режим - F11.
Так вот при его нажатии страница входит в полноэкранный режим, но в коде не меняется ничего:

document.fullscreenElement как и был null так и остается.
слушатель fullscreenchange не реагирует вообще.


Вопрос
Тогда как определить полноэкранный режим?

И здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662650/6339052 есть ответ хотьь и давно
